# How get min or max price of in stock product variation?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I use `get_variation_price` to get max or min price between product variations. but I don't know how to get min or max price between product variations which each has stock quantity bigger than 0?
Is there any idea, I get stock to this problem.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question,
this is what I did:
in `child-theme-dir/woocommerce/loop/price.php` make some changes to show the minimum price between in-stock product variations.

```
if ($product->is_type('variable')) {
        $variation_ids = $product->get_children();
        foreach( $variation_ids as $variation_id ){
            $variation = wc_get_product($variation_id);
            if( $variation->is_in_stock() )
               $price_var[] = $variation->get_price();
        }
      $price_var = min($price_var);

      echo '<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount">'.number_format($price_var, 0, ',', ',') . ' IRT'.'</span>';
    }
```